# Integrating Theano Installation with Anaconda install

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, theano, conda

I installed Theano according to the instructions on the website:

1. clone the git
2. run the command `python setup.py develop`
3. ...

I am using Pycharm with an Anaconda installation as my interpreter.  How do I integrate my new Theano installation with my Anaconda interpreter and make it part of the "Anaconda environment"?  (Theano is in `C:\Theano`, Anaconda is in `C:\...\Users\me\anaconda3\etc...`)

**My Theano installation actually shows up in my Pycharm -> Settings -> Interpreter window (location: `C:\Theano`) But when I reference it in code, it is not recognized.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to install Theano with `conda`:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/ideas theano
```

This gives you 0.7 for Windows 64. It should work with Anaconda.

Comment: Great, thanks...I was having trouble getting it through conda, so I did it manually, and ran into a dead end...